# Validate phone only when provided using Json Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Using following JSON schema to validate phone number if provided.
Accepted validation
Min length 10
Max length 20
and Pattern
If phone is null or empty, no validation is required

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "Item": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
          "Phone": {                  
                  "anyOf": [
                    {
                      "type": "integer",
                      "minLength": 10,
                      "maxLength": 20,
                      "pattern": "^(\\([0-9]{3}\\))?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
                    },
                    {
                      "type": [ "integer", "null" ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can you please suggest what is missing in the above schema?
Thank you!

Comment: Doesn't pattern only apply to strings?

Comment: Using numerical storage for phone numbers is a bad idea. Phone numbers often start with `0` or `+`, neither of which you can store in numerical types. Use strings.

Comment: That's correct, `pattern` only applies to strings, as does `minLength` and `maxLength`. This does not mean that when it's a number it will cause validation to fail, it just won't apply those constraints because they aren't applicable.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `integer` from the null case.  It's slowing so integers through, which overrides the phone number case.

Secondarily, if possible, you may want to use a later draft for your schema. Draft 4 is quite old.  Check with your validator to see if it supports a newer draft.

Answer (score 0):

There are errors in your schema, but you're missing the understanding about how JSON Schema works in terms of applicability.

JSON Schema has many keywords that are only applicable to a specific type. When the type is not that of a keywords applicability, it has no effect.

The subschema for "phone" can be simplified as the following:

```
{
  "type": ["string", "null"],
  "minLength": 10,
  "maxLength": 20,
  "pattern": "^(\\([0-9]{3}\\))?[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}$"
}
```

The keywords `minLenght`, `maxLength`, and `pattern` are only applicable to strings. If the value is not a string (and is null), those keywords are not applicable, and so are ignored.

(I've not checked your regex here, just copied what you had already.)